# How to change d3.js Chart Legend color

Tags: d3.js

i have a html file to show some CSV Data in a Chart.

that is working, but the Legend text is black. And it would be great is the Text color could fit to the Line/Axis Color.

I have tried to change it, but all examples look different to the html i have.

So please could you take a look and help me to change the Color?

i put the html and csv to plnkr

```
<http://plnkr.co/edit/HKgWYInINlVEl5lM?preview>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of a label (the tag of your legend), simply use

```css
#labelID {
   color: red; /* the color you would like to fill the label */
}
```

In your case, I would add assign an id for each label

```js
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.htmlFor = 'legnd_chk' + idx;
label.id = 'label_legend' + idx;
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
```

and add the css for the labels

```css
        #label_legend0 {
            color: blue;
        }

        #label_legend1 {
            color: red;
        }

        #label_legend2 {
            color: green;
        }

        #label_legend3 {
            color: yellow;
        }
```

See [updated plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HSuQikYlCkjoKx20?preview)

Comment: Thank you Parzival.

i tried on this code line with label.style() but id did not worked.

Comment: Now i can try to scale the Chart and make it zoomable

Comment: Of course! `label.style()` will not work since it's does not take in any parameters - you can also use `label.style.color` to change the label color. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp